# Overlap view over child UIViewController

Tags: ios, swift

I'm adding a UIView inside a child UIViewController, and I want add a little bit scale to UIView that overlap the child UIViewController but I doesn't work, I tried with `self.view.bringSubview(toFront: view)` and `view.zPositions = 1` but nothing happens.

Example: [The expected / The obtained](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9AgIe.png)

Comment: Check the clipsToBounds properties of your views. When it’s true, any content outside the view’s bounds will be clipped.